# Android check connection without context

Tags: android, connection

i would like to know if it's possible check connectivity in android without having a Context, because the thread i have running in background doesn't know the context. 
if there's no way, is a best practice passing to the thread the context?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by connectivity?

Comment: if i have wifi or 3g connection. i know i have to use the ConnectivityManager Class but the question is if a need the context

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need the `Context`. Possibly, your thread will already have access to a `Context`, courtesy of the `Runnable` it uses being an inner class of the `Activity` or `Service` that forked the thread.

Comment: i need to check the connectivity from the object runnable, i don't know the thread neither

Answer (score 1):

you can use this below method

**Kotlin :**

```
fun isNetworkAvailable1(): Boolean {
        val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
        try {
            val ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8")
            val exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor()
            return exitValue == 0
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return false
    }
```

**Java :**

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable () {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);
    } catch (IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your runnable Object will run inside Activity or Service so it will have access to its methods

I think you can simply do:

```
OuterClassName.this.getContext();
```

Comment: no because the runnable object is defined in an other java file, it's not an inner class